# How to determine if I should encode or not when changing connection charset?

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, sqlalchemy

I have a MySQL setup where all the tables/fields and charset settings are `UTF-8`, except for the connection from SqlAlchemy.

I recently changed the connection charset to `UTF-8` to use `UTF-8` everywhere.

When changing this setting, old values in the DB are rendered wrong, such as:

```
Björn => BjÃ¶rn
```

This is no problem, I just collect the values and encode them, using the encode method in python,  and put them back in again.

The problem occurs when I try to convert values inserted after the setting changed, that are already correct.

Is there a good way to determine if I should encode the value or not?

Comment: there is no bullet-proof way to guess encoding based solely on data - encoding detection is very tricky and depending on your corpora you may get false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Your old encoding, presumably, was Latin 1?

You probably *can* detect when a string was encoded with Latin-1 and not UTF-8 by looking at consecutive bytes. The UTF-8 standard has a [distinctive codepage layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout) that we could use to detect if a piece of text was encoded with either Latin-1 or UTF-8:

- Any byte in the range 00-7F is safe, of course, these are ASCII values and these codepoints match between the two encodings. No help here, no help needed.
- The bytes C0, C1 and F5-FF are *illegal* in UTF-8 encoding. Any string containing these must be Latin-1 encoded.
- Bytes in the range C2-DF *must* be followed by a byte in the range 80-BF. If you have any two bytes that do not match this you probably have a Latin-1 encoded string on your hands.

If all you ever encoded is Latin-1 characters (up to Unicode code point 255) you could stop here; anything containing bytes in the range E0-FF would be old Latin-1 data.

If you *did* add data in UTF-8 since you switched, that's outside of the Latin-1 range, you need to include the following rules too:

- Bytes in the range E0-EF mark a 3-byte UTF-8 character. The next two bytes *must* fall in the range 80-BF again.

3 UTF-8 bytes data covers the rest of the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_character_planes), you are unlikely to encode outside of this. If you do encode outside of this though, look for:

- Bytes in the range F0-F4 must be followed by exactly 3 bytes in the range 80-BF.

If *all* these criteria are matched, you *probably* have a UTF-8 string, but you can not be 100% certain. If any of them do *not* match you definitely have a Latin-1 string. But, the Latin-1 codepoints C2-DF are unlikely to ever be followed by codepoints 80-BF, as most of the latter are either control codes or more esoteric diacritical marks. Perhaps you can narrow things down further by looking for multiple 2-byte UTF-8 sequences to increase your confidence score.

So, in conclusion (tl;dr): you can find *most* Latin-1 encoded strings by looking at multi-byte sequences. If they do not fall within the rigid UTF-8 criteria, you have a Latin-1 string on your hand.